# Oracle bulk insert and ignoring errors in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, bulkinsert, odp.net

I want to bulk insert rows into an Oracle database and ideally, ignore any errors that occur on row(s) so that rows that can be inserted successfully are inserted.

For example, if there is a duplicate device_id, measurement_date pair in the table, I don't want to insert the given row. At the same time, I don't want my entire insert to error out and nothing be inserted. Is there a way to do this or would I have to catch the exception, and then retry by inserting a row at a time?

```
List<MeasurementInsertData> measurements = new List<MeasurementInsertData> measurements();

//Add some measurements...

string insertStatement = @"insert into measurement (device_id, measurement_date, value, status) 
                                values (:DeviceId, :MeasurementDate, :Value, :Status)";
using (OracleConnection dbConn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    dbConn.Open();
    OracleCommand command = dbConn.CreateCommand();

    command.CommandText = insertStatement;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.BindByName = true;
    command.ArrayBindCount = measurements.Count();

    command.Parameters.Add(":DeviceId", OracleDbType.Int32, measurements.Select(x => x.DeviceId).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
    command.Parameters.Add(":MeasurementDate", OracleDbType.Date, measurements.Select(x => x.MeasurementDate).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
    command.Parameters.Add(":Value", OracleDbType.Double, measurements.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);
    command.Parameters.Add(":Status", OracleDbType.Varchar2, measurements.Select(x => x.Status).ToArray(), ParameterDirection.Input);

    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (result == measurements.Count())
    {
        //insert successful.
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using a [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) instead of insert?

Comment: @tbone That is a good idea. I could create a staging table and use that for merging and ignore duplicates.

Comment: I was just thinking that if you're getting errors because of PK violations, you could use MERGE to just insert when not matched (you can simply ignore when matched, or do an update if you wish)